# inserting image getting async error

Tags: android, android-asynctask, parse-platform

I'm trying to insert an image to Parse cloud but I'm getting an error
Here's my code:

```
public void uploadImage() { 
File f = new File("/mnt/sdcard/test.jpg");  
Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(f.getAbsolutePath());
ParseFile file = new ParseFile("test.jpg",bitmapToByteArray(bmp));
file.saveInBackground();
test = new ParseObject("Testing");
test.put("images", file);
test.saveInBackground();    
}
```

And the error code from LogCat:

```
02-25 12:08:53.259: E/AndroidRuntime(12444): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #2
02-25 12:08:53.259: E/AndroidRuntime(12444): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
02-25 12:08:53.259: E/AndroidRuntime(12444):    at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:200)
02-25 12:08:53.259: E/AndroidRuntime(12444):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerSetException(FutureTask.java:273)
02-25 12:08:53.259: E/AndroidRuntime(12444):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:124)
02-25 12:08:53.259: E/AndroidRuntime(12444):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:307)
02-25 12:08:53.259: E/AndroidRuntime(12444):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
02-25 12:08:53.259: E/AndroidRuntime(12444):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1068)
02-25 12:08:53.259: E/AndroidRuntime(12444):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:561)
02-25 12:08:53.259: E/AndroidRuntime(12444):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1096)
02-25 12:08:53.259: E/AndroidRuntime(12444): Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: This query has an outstanding network connection. You have to wait until it's done.
02-25 12:08:53.259: E/AndroidRuntime(12444):    at com.parse.ParseFile.assertNotRunning(ParseFile.java:126)
02-25 12:08:53.259: E/AndroidRuntime(12444):    at com.parse.ParseFile.save(ParseFile.java:264)
02-25 12:08:53.259: E/AndroidRuntime(12444):    at com.parse.ParseFile.save(ParseFile.java:258)
02-25 12:08:53.259: E/AndroidRuntime(12444):    at com.parse.ParseObject.deepSave(ParseObject.java:1527)
02-25 12:08:53.259: E/AndroidRuntime(12444):    at com.parse.ParseObject.save(ParseObject.java:924)
02-25 12:08:53.259: E/AndroidRuntime(12444):    at com.parse.ParseObject$5.run(ParseObject.java:957)
02-25 12:08:53.259: E/AndroidRuntime(12444):    at com.parse.ParseObject$5.run(ParseObject.java:954)
02-25 12:08:53.259: E/AndroidRuntime(12444):    at com.parse.BackgroundTask.doInBackground(BackgroundTask.java:39)
02-25 12:08:53.259: E/AndroidRuntime(12444):    at com.parse.BackgroundTask.doInBackground(BackgroundTask.java:1)
02-25 12:08:53.259: E/AndroidRuntime(12444):    at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:185)
02-25 12:08:53.259: E/AndroidRuntime(12444):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
02-25 12:08:53.259: E/AndroidRuntime(12444):    ... 4 more
```

i don't know what it causing the error, please help me and thanks in advance

Comment: I have no idea about this API, I haven't ever used it, I was just hoping to push you in the right direction :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i have to change it to this

```
public void uploadImage()  {
        test = new ParseObject("Testing");
        File f = new File("/mnt/sdcard/test.jpg");

        Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(f.getAbsolutePath());
        file = new ParseFile("test.jpg",bitmapToByteArray(bmp));
        file.saveInBackground(new SaveCallback() {

            @Override
            public void done(ParseException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                test.put("images", file);
                test.saveInBackground();
            }
        }); 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to simultaneously save a file and an object that contains it - apparently, it's not allowed by the framework you're using. So, either don't do it or do the succeeding call as a success/complete callback to the first call.

Here is a couple of related links (btw found them by googling the exception):

[Exception "This query has an outstanding network connection.." on Android 2.2](https://parse.com/questions/exception-this-query-has-an-outstanding-network-connection-on-android-22)

[Why am I getting a "This object has an outstanding network connection" NSInternalInconsistencyException?](https://parse.com/questions/why-am-i-getting-a-this-object-has-an-outstanding-network-connection-nsinternalinconsistencyexception)

Answer (score 1):

Just get rid of the call to file.saveInBackground(). Saving the object will handle that automatically.